# How to activate spring's internal logging in a Spring application, which is not a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, logging, log4j

In the spring source code I see:

```
boolean debug = logger.isDebugEnabled();
```

What should I do to make `debug` true?

With Spring Boot, if I add the property `logging.level.root=DEBUG`, it works. But not in Spring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable logging in spring framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002532/enable-logging-in-spring-framework)

Comment: With Spring Boot, if I add the property logging.level.root=DEBUG, it works. But not in Spring.

Answer (score -1):

Tested on springboot 2.1.9.RELEASE

1. Set root log level directly in config file `application.yml`

```
logging:
  level:
    root: trace
```

2. create file "logback.xml" under resources directory in maven project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="false" scanPeriod="1 seconds">
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} [%file : %line] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

`debug="true"` in config will output many useful debug log,such as

```
10:02:15,511 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/win/proj/my_web/manage/target/classes/logback.xml]
10:02:15,909 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to TRACE
10:02:15,909 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [stdout] to Logger[ROOT]
```

if you see below output `Propagating`, it means you have config log level in somewhere, like `logging.level.root=info` in `application.properties`

```
10:02:17,026 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@495b0487 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
```